# Easy to read scientific notation on Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point, scientific-notation

I have a Postgresql table column which's type is `numeric(20,4)`. When I play with the data through rails console, ActiveRecord display the values in scientific notation.

All I can think of adding `attribute :column_name, :float` to the related modal, but not sure if there will be any side effects because of it.

So the question is; does anyone one if there is anything I can do to make it easier for reading the data on rails console and do not have any side effects on the app itself?

Comment: Just find out awesome_print solves this if I use `ap` to print. I guess that's something ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkeypatch specifically BigDecimal class specifically for console

development.rb

```
  console do
    class BigDecimal
      def inspect
        to_f
      end
    end
  end
```